# How I can do a mean with three conditions in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, mean

I am trying to do a mean with three conditions, like:

```
mean(subset(dados_2021, dados_2021$city==1 & dados_2021$city==2 & dados_2021$sex=1)$age)
```

It returns to me "NaN".

I want a mean of age considering only these two cities and considering only who is of the mentioned sex.

I try to do a mean of age considering these two cities e the condition of sex.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: try to change to `sex == 1`. Perhaps the typo is to blame?

Comment: Nothing can satisfy `dados_2021$city==1 & dados_2021$city==2`. Do you mean `|`?

Comment: Ok, this makes sense! I was not aware of this operator. Are we now considering these two cities together?

Comment: Yes, both cities combined. | means "OR" so `dados_2021$city == 1 | dados_2021$city == 2` will return all values that are either 1 or 2. You can also use `%in%` to supply a list of values e.g. `dados_2021$city %in% c(1, 2)`. Running your code with all the corrections suggested will return a single mean age value.